# Launch application after installation apk in rooted device android

Tags: android, apk, root

Hi I want to install apk from sd card in rooted android device, I installed successful apk but after installation doesn't open application, it shows board menu in android ,how to launch application after installation

```
String path = "/sdcard/Android/data/com.apk.applicaiton/files/ApkFile/test.apk";

public static Boolean InstallApk(String path)
{
    File file = new File(path);
    if(file.exists()){
        try {
            Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"su","-c","pm install -r -d " + path});
            proc.waitFor();
            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getErrorStream()));
            String line;
            Boolean hasError = false;
            while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
                if(line.contains("Failure")){
                    hasError = true;
                }
            }
            if(proc.exitValue() != 0 || hasError){
                return false;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }else{
        Timber.i("Path is not found:%s", path);
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: start main intent of the app ?

Comment: I tried,it doesn't work, applications only installed